# Symfony 6 mailer DSN with SMTP doesn't send mails

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-messenger, symfony-mailer

I'm trying Symfony 6 Mailer with different SMTP servers and none of them is working.

The messages are queued but not sent. I tried from different servers to discard a firewall or port issue.

There are no log messages or exceptions, so I'm quite lost.

This are some DSN I tried:

```
MAILER_DSN="smtp://email%40example.com:123456@host.example.com:587?encryption=tls"
MAILER_DSN="smtp://email@example.com:123456@host.example.com:587?encryption=tls"
MAILER_DSN="smtp://email@example.com:123456@host.example.com:587"
```

I actually tried many DSN combinations with/without encryption. I suspect the problem is in the DSN string as, if I try wrong hosts or passwords, the effect is the same.

This is a long lasting problem I haven't been able to resolve in a long time.

And this is the sending code:

```
use Symfony\Component\Mime\Email;

$email = (new Email())
        ->from($this->parameterBag->get('app.message.email_from'))
        ->to($to)
        ->subject($subject)
        ->text($text)
        ->html($text);

$sentMessage = $this->mailer->send($email);
```

`mailer.yaml` content:

```
framework:
    mailer:
        dsn: '%env(MAILER_DSN)%'
```

And `messenger.yaml` content:

```
framework:
    messenger:
        failure_transport: failed

        transports:
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html#transport-configuration
            async:
                dsn: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%'
                options:
                    use_notify: true
                    check_delayed_interval: 60000
                retry_strategy:
                    max_retries: 3
                    multiplier: 2
            failed: 'doctrine://default?queue_name=failed'
            # sync: 'sync://'

        routing:
            Symfony\Component\Mailer\Messenger\SendEmailMessage: async
            Symfony\Component\Notifier\Message\ChatMessage: async
            Symfony\Component\Notifier\Message\SmsMessage: async

            # Route your messages to the transports
            # 'App\Message\YourMessage': async
```

Comment: And do you have a `messenger.yaml` as well ?

Comment: @DylanKAS added this information also. I wasn't aware of this file, so it must be with the default content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current messenger configuration, emails are not sent directly, but only when `messenger:consume` is called.

That's because messenger is queuing emails (or other messages such as SMS) instead of being immediately sent.

You can learn more about the [messenger component here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html#transports-async-queued-messages), but if you want to ignore it for now and just send your emails synchronously by modifying your transport configuration.

```
framework:
    messenger:
        transports:
            async: 'sync://'
        routing:
            Symfony\Component\Mailer\Messenger\SendEmailMessage: async
            Symfony\Component\Notifier\Message\ChatMessage: async
            Symfony\Component\Notifier\Message\SmsMessage: async

            # Route your messages to the transports
            # 'App\Message\YourMessage': async
```